# Restrict user from changing to a directory outside of /home/username

Tags: command-line, permissions, ssh

As a reference, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.5

I feel like I've looked at a hundred of these and for some reason, none have worked. This is most likely due to a lack of understanding on my part about what exactly I'm doing. What I'm trying to do is set up a user, and only let that user have access to their directory and anything under their home directory. However, I do not want them to be able to access anything above this home directory (meaning they should not be allowed to change the directory by doing `cd ..` while in `/home/username`).

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Set up the user `username`.
2. Added the user to a special group so that they and other users could edit some files, we can call this `sgroup`.
3. Set up the files `username` needs to be able to run things like mysql, ls, vim, etc. by issuing the following commands:

   ```
   [AS ROOT]
   mount --rbind /bin /home/username/sprg/bin
   mount --rbind /dev /home/username/sprg/dev
   mount --rbind /etc /home/username/sprg/etc
   mount --rbind /lib /home/username/sprg/lib
   mount --rbind /proc /home/username/sprg/proc
   mount --rbind /sbin /home/username/sprg/sbin
   mount --rbind /sys /home/username/sprg/sys
   mount --rbind /usr /home/username/sprg/usr
   ```

`root` currently owns everything under `sprg` including the folder itself.

4. Edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and changed the line: `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` to `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`. At the end of the file, I added the following:

   ```
   Match user username
       ChrootDirectory /home/username
       AllowTCPForwarding no
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
   ```
5. Restarted ssh via `sudo service ssh restart`.

Now, when I change my user to `username` via `su - username`, I am still able to view files and folders outside of my `/home/username` directory. Also note that `root` owns `/home/username`.

To wrap it up, all I'm looking to do is have the user log into a terminal via ssh, get directed to their home directory (which already happens), and then disallows them from ever accessing another directory **UNLESS** it is under `/home/username`. In which case, they are free to do as they please under that directory.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `rbash`? It's a restricted shell that prevents many things, including changing directories.

Comment: Have looked into using selinux to do this? I think I recall that being a configurable option using selinux

Comment: @NonnyMoose I don't want to completely prevent changing directories though. If the user makes a folder under their home directory, I want them to be able to move into it. Does `rbash` completely disallow `cd`?

Answer (score 2):

> Now, when I change my user to username via `su - username`, I am still able to view files and folders outside of my `/home/username` directory. Also note that root owns `/home/username`.

Restrictions on SSH aren't going to affect `su`. The settings seem fine to me, so you should test it by doing `ssh username@localhost` and `sftp username@localhost`. Since you have said that the user logs in via SSH, given these settings, `su` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I almost just said that. I really should read. ;)

Comment: Also note that if the user can become root they can break out of the chroot.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. bash ends up not being started because I assume it's looking for `/bin/bash` instead of `/home/username/sprg/bin/bash`. I updated the `PATH` variable in `.bashrc` and in `.profile`. It still seems to disconnect without warning. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: @Alex you have forced SFTP. Only SFTP should work.

Comment: @muru how can I allow SFTP and SSH?

Comment: @muru Just removing that internal SFTP command does not seem to work. Any ssh connection still closes automatically.

Comment: @Alex your bind mounts all seem to be to inside a subdirectory of the chroot directory, instead of directly inside the chroot directory.

Comment: @muru Is that not allowed even when updating the users `PATH`? I thought anything created underneath the chroot directory is fine.

Comment: @Alex o.O so when SSH starts the shell, `/bin/bash` is needed but everything is in `/sprg/bin`, all the libraries are in `/sprg/lib`, and so on. No, paths relative to `/` must be the same relative to the chroot directory. Either change the chroot directory or change the config.

Comment: @muru I mounted everything in the correct directory (ie. `/home/username/bin/bash` now exists). However my window doesnt seem to work as it immediately disconnects (with PuTTy). Is there something else I should do?

Comment: @Alex Now, checking SSH logs would be the best thing to do

Comment: I figured it out by enabling PuTTy logging. It seems that it can still not find bash. This is strange as I explicitly put bin under `/home/username/bin/bash`, however it says it can not find `/bin/bash`